# light_mode shadow_only material in godot 4 for 2D light

Tags: godot, godot-shader-language

I want to make a 2D object that becomes transparent when light hits it. This is completely opposite to the `light_only` light mode. To be honest light_only doesn't work in Godot 4.0, it's fixed in 4.1

In Godot 3 I would use shader with `AT_LIGHT_PASS`. But in Godot 4 `AT_LIGHT_PASS` always get false.
Also I was trying to use `light()` in Godot shaders but it's only adds on `COLOR`, so I can't set alpha 0.0 on `LIGHT` to make texture transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform sampler2D SCREEN_TEXTURE : hint_screen_texture;
uniform vec4 on_light_color : source_color;

void light(){
    LIGHT = texture(SCREEN_TEXTURE, SCREEN_UV);
}
```